# Spring factory bean for implementations with different dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-ioc

Imagine I have a Storage bean, which incapsulates logic, related to storing my entities.

```
public interface Storage {
   Object get(String id);
   String save(Object obj);
}
```

And I have 3 implementations:

```
public FileStorage implements Storage { ... } // needs FileService
public RedisStorage implements Storage { ... } // needs JedisPool, RedisService and RedisSerializer
public MixedStorage implements Storage { ... } // combines other Storages
```

I also have 2 properties:

```
redis.enabled
file.enabled
```

Depending on these properties, I have to either create one of the beans, or both of them using `MixedStorage` (or none, but this is out of the question scope).

I have created a StorageFactory factory-bean:

```
public class StorageFactory {
   // decide which impl to create basing on properties
}
```

Now I am passing all the dependent resources I need for all implementations (`RedisSerializer`, `JedisPool`, `RedisService`, `FileService`). Number of these resources can grow very faster, while adding new implementations.

Is there any way not to pass all the dependencies, but initialize them later?

I am using XML

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it be useful for you but using annotations it is look like this:

For beans:

```
@Component("FileStorage")
public FileStorage implements Storage { ... }
```

For service:

```
@Service
public class StorageFactory {
   @Autowired
   private Map<String,Storage> storageMap;//where key - bean name, value - class instance
}
```

And yes, the map will contains all beans but you will able to implement some logic based on your property file.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about something similiar: 
creating beans beinhg conditional on property (but it looks ugly in XML)
and then injecting a list into the factory. 
In xml we can do the same autowire using `<bean ... autowire="byType" .. />`